# sed to insert a comment character over a remote connection

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to search a file for the occurrence of the word Logmon anywhere on a multi-lined file. For each row where a match is found, insert a # at the beginning of the row.
I am able to accomplish this by using:

```
sed -i '/Logmon/ s/^/#/' nrds.cfg
```

The above accomplishes my objective, however, I am having issues doing this for a list of remote servers. Below is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/ksh

DEST="/usr/local/nrdp/clients/nrds/"

for x in `cat /home/jack/hostlist`
do
SSH_STATUS=$(ssh -n -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$x "pwd" >/dev/null)
if [[ $? = "0" ]];then
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $x "sudo /usr/localcw/bin/eksh -c 'cd $DEST; sed -i "/Logmon/ s/^/#/" nrds.cfg'"
else
echo "Cannot connect to $x" >> badhosts
fi
done
```

The above returns the following error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: missing command

I suspect the problem is either with my quoting or I need to escape one or more of the forward slashes. I have tried numerous things and always seem to get the same error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quoting issue. This is what happens:

```
"sudo /usr/localcw/bin/eksh -c 'cd $DEST; sed -i "/Logmon/ s/^/#/" nrds.cfg'"
^ double quoting starts                 ends here^    starts anew^      ends^
```

Because of this, `sshd` on the remote side runs:

```
sudo /usr/localcw/bin/eksh -c 'cd $DEST; sed -i /Logmon/ s/^/#/ nrds.cfg'
```

`eksh` gets:

```
cd $DEST; sed -i /Logmon/ s/^/#/ nrds.cfg
```

so now expression #1 for `sed` is just `/Logmon/`. To fix this you should escape double quotes that should get to the remote side, like this:

```
"sudo /usr/localcw/bin/eksh -c 'cd \"$DEST\" && sed -i \"/Logmon/ s/^/#/\" nrds.cfg'"
```

There are few extra improvements:

- I also quote `$DEST` to ensure you get `cd "<local value of $DEST>"` on the remote side instead of `cd <local value of $DEST>`. This makes no difference in your particular case now, when the value is `/usr/local/nrdp/clients/nrds/`; but if you changed this path to e.g. `/foo/bar baz/` then it would break your "quoteless" `cd` invocation.
- `&&` ensures `sed` is run only if `cd` succeeds (I'm not sure it works in `eksh`, whatever it is; it works in many shells though). If for some reason `cd` fails then `sed` won't act in your starting directory. Again this will probably never hit you, still it's a good general practice.

Comment: This is awesome !!  Thanks so much Kamil and for the explanation. This works great !!